# High resolution autoplot function in R studio

Tags: r, plot

I get one good plot with autoplot function in R studio. If I click in zoom a get a expected picture of my plot. However i would like to export in high resolution. This was my last command.

```
autoplot(bed, layout = "karyogram", aes(color = score, fill = score), res = 1200)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `tiff("figurename.tif", units="in", width=11, height=8.5, res=300)` before start the comands. After, put `dev.off()` to write a plot as tiff format in your disk.